# I get an error connecting to a MS Access database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to connect to a MS Access database with my Windows Forms application, but I get this error:

Error : ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been intialized"
[image]

Please help
this is the code::

namespace logintrial4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\shiwa\source\repos\logintrial4\bin\Debug\log4.accdb");
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into log4 values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you copy all of that code and show it on here please? It'll be easier to identify by looking all of it.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

You missed a line ,you have to set connection to cmd after initializing cmd

```
cmd.Connection = foo;
```

Complete code :

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\shiwa\source\repos\logintrial4\bin\Debug\log4.accdb");
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into log4 values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
    con.Close();
```

Comment: nope , it shows the following error "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find output "@Maghilvannan